# Schur complement for linear matrix inequality (LMI)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

Given the following inequality

\begin{align}
& \gamma \left( Q - (A Q + BY)^T Q^{-1} (A Q + BY) \right) - Y^T R^{1 \over 2} R^{1\over 2} Y - Q Q_1^{1\over2} Q_1^{1\over2} Q \succeq 0  \tag{1}
\end{align}

where $\gamma > 0$ is a scalar, $Q \succ 0$, $R \succ 0$ and $Q_1 \succ 0$ are symmetric matrices. The notation $G \succ 0$ denotes that $G$ is positive definite and $G \succeq 0$ denotes that $G$ is positive semidefinite .

How do I convert it to the following form by applying Schur complement?

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
Q & (A Q + BY)^T &  Q Q_1^{1\over2} & Y^T R^{1 \over 2}\\
(A Q + BY) & Q & 0 & 0 \\
Q_1^{1\over2} Q  & 0 & \gamma I & 0 \\
 R^{1\over 2} Y & 0 & 0 & \gamma I
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

I understand
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
E & F \\ F^T & G
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \tag{3}
\end{align}

is equivalent to the inequalities:

\begin{align}
G \succ 0,\qquad E - F G^{-1} F^T \succ 0 \tag{4}
\end{align}

or equivalently,

\begin{align}
E \succ 0,\qquad G - F^T E^{-1} F \succ 0 \tag{5}
\end{align}

How do I extend the core ideas from inequalities $(3)$-$(5)$ to inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$?

I want to understand how to arrive at a form like (2) from (1) for the purpose of constructing LMI problems in control theory. This example is from the proof of theorem 1 in the [Robust Constrained Model Predictive Control using Linear Matrix Inequalities](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4892738.pdf) [PDF]. Is there a general method or technique to get to (2) from (1)?

Comment: Are you sure about (4) and (5)? Take a look at [this](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf).

Comment: Indeed $\gamma > 0$.  I'm excited now because you clearly know this stuff.

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental because I am getting stuck at the same place. Is there a particular section of the note I should be focusing on?

Comment: Specifically, how do I get to a simple expression without blocks of 2x2 matrices.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Thanks, I just had to simplify the expression resulting from the first application of the rule, then repeat process.  Do you have any hints as to getting to (2) from (1)?

Comment: **Hint:** take the $4 \times 4$ matrix and think of it as a block matrix whose northwest block is $Q$ and whose southeast block is a $3 \times 3$ block diagonal matrix. Going from (2) to (1) is easy.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I understand going from (2) to (1). I want to know hot to go from (1) to (2)

Comment: Then start by dividing both sides by $\gamma > 0$ and reverse every step of (2) to (1).